# 18.04 Screen orientation rotates at random after new install

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

My screen rotation problem seems the same as [blimp1899 from Dec 9](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195020/laptop-screen-keeps-changing-orientation) which had no answer. My laptop sits on a desk, with 4 cords which make it very difficult to keep picking it up and turning it around to re-orient it. Lap is an HP Pavillion. Has been happening since I finished downloading Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to Settings -> Devices-> Displays and, as per  https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/look-resolution.html
lock the system down into Landscape mode.